# Error with PHPMailer

Tags: php, mailer

Hello everyone i have been getting this error and dont know how to fix it.

> {"response":"error","message":"You must provide at least one recipient
>   email address."}

This is the code.

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

//recipient data
$toemail = $_POST['contact@spadaweb.com']; // Your Email Address
$toname = $_POST['Spadaweb, INC']; // Your Name

//sender data
$name = $_POST['contact-form-name'];
$email = $_POST['contact-form-email'];
$service = $_POST['contact-form-service'];
$subject = $_POST['contact-form-subject'];
$message = $_POST['contact-form-message'];


if( isset( $_POST['contact-form-submit'] ) ) {

if( $name != '' AND $email != '' AND $subject != '' AND $message != '' ) {

    $body = "Name: $name <br><br>Email: $email <br><br>Service: $service <br>            <br>Message: $message";

    $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );    
    $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );            
    $mail->AddAddress( $toemail , $toname );            
    $mail->Subject = $subject;            
    $mail->MsgHTML( $body );

    $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

    if( $sendEmail == true ):
        $arrResult = array ('response'=>'success');
    else:
        $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error','message'=>$mail->ErrorInfo);       
    endif;
    } else {
    $arrResult = array ('response'=>'empty');            
    }

} else {
    $arrResult = array ('response'=>'unexpected');
}
echo json_encode($arrResult);
?>
```

I have changed the email etc to mine and i keep getting the above error? Currently hosted on a bluehost vps cent os server as well. DKIM is enabled on this particular account? Thanks for looking over the problem!

Comment: `$toemail = $_POST['contact@spadaweb.com']` - is that the name of your input field? That's populating the To address with the contents of a field in your form called `contact@spadaweb.com`. Try hardwiring it to `$toemail = 'contact@spadaweb.com'` and see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$toemail = $_POST['contact@spadaweb.com']; // Your Email Address
$toname = $_POST['Spadaweb, INC']; // Your Name
```

This needs to be changed since you are giving it the actual variables and not trying to get the posts.

```
$toemail = 'contact@spadaweb.com'; // Your Email Address
$toname = 'Spadaweb, INC'; // Your Name
```

Now it should be able to send.

Comment: Thankyou Very much, I had a feeling it would be something very simple like that!